# Drag and Drop not dropping into shopping cart

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable

I can drag the images of album art and they clone and go back to their original place when dropped away from the cart button, but when I drop it on the cart button it doesn't update the cart, it just goes back to its original state. Why is this occuring?

```
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var AlbumToAdd = ui.draggable.data("id");
                if (AlbumToAdd != '') {
                    // Perform the ajax post
                    $.post("/ShoppingCart/DragToCart", { "id": AlbumToAdd },
                        function (data) {
                            // Successful requests get here
                            // Update the page elements
                            $('#cart-status').text("Cart (" + data.CartCount + ")");
                        });
                }
            }
        });
```

Controller

```
//
// GET: /Store/DragToCart/5
public ActionResult DragToCart(int id)
{
    // Retrieve the album from the database
    var addedAlbum = storeDB.Albums
        .Single(album => album.AlbumId == id);

    // Add it to the shopping cart
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

    cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum);

    var results = new DragToCartViewModel
    {
        Message = Server.HtmlEncode(addedAlbum.Title) +
            "Your cart has been updated",
        CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
        CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
        AddedId = id
    };
    return Json(results);
```

Comment if you want to see more code

Answer (score 1):

Have you found out which part of the code doesn't work? Is it the droppable JS or the controller? If you put alert("blah"); in your JS you can find out which code doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I added an alert and nothing happens, the alert doesn't show and it just does what it did before

Comment: where did you put the alert? If you put it `// Perform the ajax post` there and `// Update the page elements` with different values, you can see which one doesn't fire

Comment: I added the alerts as you said but no alerts appear

Comment: Then either something goes wrong in this line: `var AlbumToAdd = ui.draggable.data("id");` or your droppable element doesn't have the `class="droppable"`. If it's the first, try to alert the AlbumToAdd var and see what it says. If its "undefined" then there's something wrong in that line.

Comment: I've put an alert on the drop function and that's not firing so it's not even registering that anythings happening

Comment: Did you give your cart button a droppable class? And if so, you did download the jquery-ui with droppable selected (you can choose to not include that functionality when you download jquery-ui)

Comment: Then I can only advice to create a simple new html file with just 2 elements: a draggable element and a droppable element and try to make it as basic as possible. Try to get that one to work (with just an alert in the droppable function) and try to find out what you're doing wrong.